# Использование iostream_operator для записи в файл

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, я  пытаюсь записать и прочитать созданный класс `WRstrcut`, используя `ostream_iterator` и `istream_iterator`. С записью проблем нет, а вот с чтением есть. Ошибка такая:

> Error  C2678   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    ttttt   c:\users\desktop\ttttt\ttttt\wrstruct.h    32  '

Для того , чтобы произвести запись и чтение я перегружаю операторы ввода\вывода в классе.

Почему происходит такая ошибка, подскажите , пожалуйста, как ее исправить?

Код:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <istream>

class WRstruct
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string number;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const WRstruct&);
    friend std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& is, WRstruct&);
public:
    WRstruct(){};
    void write();
    void read();
    ~WRstruct(){};
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const WRstruct& p)
{
    os << "User Name: " << p.name << std::endl
        << "Number: " << p.number << std::endl
        << std::endl;
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, WRstruct& p)
{
    is >>"Say name:">>p.name >>"Say number:">> p.number;
    return is;
}
```

Функция `void read()`:

```
void WRstruct::read()
{
    std::vector<WRstruct> vec;

    std::ifstream readFile("temp.txt");
    std::istream_iterator<WRstruct> istr(readFile);
    copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), istr);

    std::istream_iterator<WRstruct> end_istr;
    copy(istr, end_istr, back_inserter(vec));

    std::ostream_iterator<WRstruct> osIter(std::cout," ");
    copy(vec.begin(),vec.end(),osIter);

}
```

Функция `void write()`:

```
void WRstruct::write()
{
    std::vector<WRstruct> vecP;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<WRstruct>(std::cin),
    std::istream_iterator<WRstruct>(), std::back_inserter(vecP));
    std::ofstream temp("temp.txt", std::ios::out);
    std::ostream_iterator<WRstruct>temp_itr(temp, "\n");
    std::copy(vecP.begin(), vecP.end(), temp_itr);
}
```

main():

```
#include <iostream>
#include "WRstruct.h"

int main()
{
    WRstruct r;
    r.write();
    //r.read();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Abyx изменил (полный текст ошибки), по поводу "минимальный полный код" я Вас не понял. Я показал все реализованные функции, так как считаю , что они должны быть тоже показаны.

Comment: @Abyx не было того извините

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is >>"Say name:">>p.name;` - это неправильно. Поток ввода не умеет выводить текст. Разделите вывод и ввод:

```
cout << "Say name:";
is >> p.name;
```

Comment: Спасибо, я понял! Это помогло, только теперь ошибка другая :(( :`Error C2678 binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const WRstruct' (or there is no acceptable conversion) ttttt c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 2316"` , я думаю нужна перегрузка  ` = `. Могли вы помочь с этим? Почему так и где этот знак проявляется?

Comment: Получается, что нужно перегружать оператор '='? 
`  c:\users\\desktop\ttttt\ttttt\wrstruct.h(21): note: could be 'WRstruct &WRstruct::operator =(const WRstruct &)'
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(2316): note: while trying to match the argument list '(const WRstruct, WRstruct)' `

Comment: я не понимаю, какой константе:(((((((((((((